# Issues with overloading Order

Tags: packages

I am pretty new to Mathematica(about 90 minutes) and I have encountered a problem. I have searched the web pretty comprehensively and came up with nothing.

For a computing problem that I am solving, I needed to use this package 
http://www.theophys.kth.se/~phl/Mathematica/

I specifically need to use the CompressedTransferMatrix1F method.

However, when I try the example as mentioned in the package documentation, this is what happens, and the matrix is not as I expect it to be. 
[image]

I am guessing this has something to do with the fact that Order method is overloaded is the package. It takes a single argument of type graph and returns the number of vertices in a graph. And the default order method in Mathematica takes 2 arguments. Help to resolve this issue is really appreciated.

> (* Order::usage *) If[!StringMatchQ[Order::usage, "*Order[g]*"],
>     Order::usage = Order::usage <>  "\n Order[g] returns the number of
>   vertices in a graph g."

If post language is not clear, feel free to edit. Thank you.